# Are Silverlight XAP != Windows Phone XAP

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone

I develop a Silverlight application and I renamed the extension from XAP to ZIP. With WinZip I can view all my files and folders of the Silverlight application.

I have no experience with Windows Phone development so, recently I try to do the same with a Windows Phone XAP file and renamed it to ZIP.

When I try do open with WinZip I get the message:

"Cannot open file 'xxxx.zip'. It does not appear to be a valid archive"

I try the same with WinRAR, 7Zip, PeaZIP and I can't still open the file.

My question is:

Are Silverlight XAPs and Windows Phone XAPs different things?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the if and what the differences might be but I do know that you can open Windows Phone XAP files using those programs (at least WinRAR). You can verify this by creating a WP project in Visual Studio, build the project and then go to the /bin/release or /bin/debug directory and open the XAP file with WinRAR for example. I just did this with a Windows Phone 8 app built using Visual Studio 2012.

BUT you can only do that to XAP files which are NOT signed. This is because when the XAP file is uploaded to the store they are signed to protect them and guarantee that no-one has tampered with the code. The XAP files are automatically signed when uploaded to the store (see submission step 4 here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj206729(v=vs.105).aspx).

More about signing of XAP files for LightSwitch can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg481772%28v=vs.110%29.aspxhttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg481772%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but I would guess it works in a similair way for Windows Phone XAP files.

Answer (score 0):

The spec, how they work, and layout is the same. However the binary executables in them are different and compiled for the specific platform.